# Unable to assign struct pointer to memory array

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to point a memory address in struct :

```
    typedef struct {
        uint32_t dataAddress;
    } response_struct;
```

to an initialized array:

```
uint8_t *msg = NULL;
msg = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*LEN);

    printf("Init: \n");
    for (i=0; i<LEN; i++) {
        msg[i] = i;
        printf("%d ", msg[i]);
    }
```

which is displaying its contents properly, however, after assigning it:

```
// case 1:
(response_struct_ptr->dataAddress) = (uint32_t) msg;

// or with case 2:
void assign_value_to_memory_address_given (uint8_t *msg, response_struct *response_struct_ptr) {
    (response_struct_ptr->dataAddress) = (uint32_t) msg;

}

// e.g. assign_value_to_memory_address_given (msg, response_struct_ptr);
```

the display run into a Segmentation fault (core dumped)

```
    for (i=0; i < LEN; i++)  // message fixed at length 10
        printf(" %x",  ((uint8_t*) response_struct_ptr->dataAddress)[i]);

    printf("\n");
```

Can someone point where might be incorrect?
Thanks.

Comment: What's incorrect is the part where `dataAddress` is not a pointer, but an integer (and all the associated casting). Why not just give `dataAddress` its proper type?

Comment: i was hoping to use `dataAddress` to store the address.
how shall we correct the program if we wish to retain that as a `uint32_t` type storage?

Comment: You don't, if you're on a 64-bit platform, because pointers just don't fit in 32 bits.

Comment: What value is in response_struct_ptr?

Comment: @melpomene, you are right, it works for 32 bit machines, but not 64-bit machines. I am trying to find a way to re-order it for 64-bit. Any code suggestions?

Comment: @immibis response_struct_ptr is still able to contain the address to *msg.

Comment: As I said before, my suggestion is to give `dataAddress` its proper type, as in `uint8_t *dataAddress;`.

Comment: `(response_struct_ptr->dataAddress) = (uint32_t) msg;` does not make response_struct_ptr point to the address that msg points to, if that's what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code may work for a 32-bit device but not 64-bits.

As suggested by @melpomene, if you're on a 64-bit platform, because pointers just don't fit in 32 bits. Hence, remediation can be made to the code by changing the type:

```
    typedef struct {
        //uint32_t dataAddress;
        uint8_t *dataAddress;
    } response_struct;
```

And suggested by @immibis to remediate the code line:

```
//(response_struct_ptr->dataAddress) = (uint32_t) msg;
(response_struct_ptr->dataAddress) = msg;
```

Comment: You don't need those parentheses, by the way: `response_struct_ptr->dataAddress = msg;` is fine.